# Differential equations of the form $\frac{dy}{dt}=ky\left(1-\frac{y}{N(t)}\right)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a general method to solve differential equations of the form $$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky\left(1-\frac{y}{N(t)}\right)$$
where $N(t)$ is a non-constant function?

In particular I would be interested in linear, exponential, logarithmic, or polynomial $N(t)$s.

Answer (score 6):

This is a Bernoulli differential equation.  With the change of variables $u = 1/y$, it becomes the constant-coefficient linear differential equation
$$ \dfrac{du}{dt} = - k u + \dfrac{k}{N(t)}$$
which can be solved in closed form provided you can integrate $\dfrac{\exp(kt)}{N(t)}$

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from Robert Israel's answer, the solution of $$\frac{dy}{dt}=ky\left(1-\frac{y}{N(t)}\right)$$ is given by $$y=\frac{e^{k t}}{c+k \int_0^t \frac{e^{k z}}{N(z)} \, dz}$$ The easiest case I found was, as one could expect, for $N(t)=e^{a+bt}$. For such a case $$\int_0^t \frac{e^{k z}}{N(z)} \, dz=\frac{e^{-a} \left(1-e^{t (k-b)}\right)}{b (b-k)}$$